# How to know what table a result came from when using UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using a union query:

```
SELECT snippet_id, title FROM tbl_snippets WHERE title LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT tag_id, tag FROM tbl_tags WHERE tag LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT category_id, category FROM tbl_categories WHERE category LIKE ?
```

How will I know which table a result came from?snippet_id, tag_id  and category_id doesn't have a prefix like SN, TG, or CI that I could use to determine where a result came from. 
The results are basically put together in one result so I don't really know if what I'm thinking is possible that's why I came asking here.

Comment: You can add an extra field to each select statement and include table name there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not adding the prefix as a separate (computed) column?

```
SELECT 'SN' prefix, snippet_id, title FROM tbl_snippets WHERE title LIKE ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TA', tag_id, tag FROM tbl_tags WHERE tag LIKE ?
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA', category_id, category FROM tbl_categories WHERE category LIKE ?
```

**Edit:** I have also changed `UNION [DISTINCT]` to `UNION ALL` - for the following reasons:

- If the original query produces different results for `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, introducing the prefix will change the number of result rows.
- In most cases `UNION ALL` is slightly faster than `UNION DISTINCT`.
- Most people actually want to have `UNION ALL`.

Comment: The UNION ALL is probably unnecessary since the prefix will make the rows unique across tables (assuming no dupes within tables)

Comment: @JohnFx: Thanks. I have changed it to `UNION ALL` because `UNION [DISTINCT]` is confusing. I edited my answer accordingly.